# Type object 'User' has no attribute 'objects' (AbstractUser) python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

app name **backend**

User object is returning  error :

```
users = User.objects.filter(fb_userid=fb_user_id)
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'objects'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    fb_userid = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
from backend.models import *

def fb_login(request):
    # permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'fb_user_id' not in request.data:
            return Response({'error':'missing fb_user_id'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        fb_user_id = str(request.data['fb_user_id'])

        users = User.objects.filter(fb_userid=fb_user_id)
        if users.count() == 0:
            user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=fb_user_id, email='fb@fb.net')
            if created:
                user.save()
        else:
            user = users[0]
        token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)[0]
        # Likes
        likeIds = []
        likes = ImageLike.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)
        for like in likes:
            likeIds.append(like.image.id)
        # Saved Places
        savedIds = []
        saved = SavedRestaurants.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)
        for save in saved:
            savedIds.append(save.restaurant.id)
        jsonData = { 'token': token.key, 'saved': savedIds, 'likes': likeIds }
        return Response(jsonData)
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.User'
```

[image]

User object is returning  error :

users = User.objects.filter(fb_userid=fb_user_id)
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: Point your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` from `settings.py` to your `app.CustomUserModel`

Comment: From where did you imported `User` in your view ?

Comment: from .models import User
from backend.models import *

Comment: What's in backend.models ? Any User there (directly or indirectly) ?

Comment: backend is my app this code is in backend app

Comment: try to replace the `*` in the import with list.

Comment: use `python manage.py shell` to open interactive shell, and inspect the `User` class with `dir(User)`. check if the `User` class is pointing to your `User` model class or not.

Comment: it is working fine
 >>> from backend.models import *
>>> dir(User)
['DoesNotExist', 'EMAIL_FIELD', 'Meta', 'MultipleObjectsReturned', _', '__delattr__', '__dict_unique_together', '_'email_user', 'fb_userid',

Comment: why you import the `User` two way? you should to remove the `from .models import User` any way.

Comment: This code is working good in Django shell

Answer (score 0):

Try set

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.user'.
```

Comment: @a_k_v my code is working in shell but in djnago web i'm not able to import User model

Comment: Did you try to populate User model through shell ?